# Multiply By seven

Tags: c

I was asked this interview question:
what is the quickest way to multiply a number by 7.
she told me not to use any of the  `+ , - , * , /` operators.
In tense,i could not answer the question.

I know the quickest way to multiply a number by 8 is `n<<3`
but can `n*7` be acheived?

Comment: hm, what's "told me **to to** use any +,-,*,/ operator **In tense**" ?

Comment: FWIW, on modern hardware the quickest way is to use `*` anyway. It's quick to type and quick to understand and it executes quickly. Not what your interviewer was looking for though…

Comment: Terrible interview question.  Any modern compiler, for any language, will already produce optimal code for "7*n"...  And that will be true on today's hardware, tomorrow's, next year's, and next decade's, unlike whatever bit-twiddling hack your interviewer had in mind.

Comment: Minor typo, but I think you meant to say "to **not** use" those operators.

Comment: Can you clarify which operators are allowed and which are not ?

Comment: @Nemo : actually, I kind of like that question... however, I would only be satisfied by an answer such as yours, that in most situations we should trust the compiler to generate the quickest possible code for the situation.

Comment: The question is still very badly posed - even after correcting the original typo (the crucial missing "not"), it's still not clear which operators *are* permissible. Voting to close unless it get's cleaned up and improved.

Comment: @ Paul .corrected the type mistakes.It seems fine to me now.

Comment: @Rahul: you *still* haven't stated which operators *are* permissible, which makes the question kind of pointless and vague.

Comment: In any case, fundamentally changing the question by inverting the set of allowable operators AFTER you get half a dozen answers is bad form, IMHO.

Comment: The point here is that they want to make you think to how compiler/assembly coder did it.

Comment: I have a problem with the term *quickest*.  Not using the fundamental math operators results in an operation that is not quick.

Comment: For info, a colleague of mine has solved this:- `log(pow(exp(multiplier),n))` in C++

Comment: While it's a bad mistake for the question to have initially listed `+, -, *, /` as available operators, it should have been pretty obvious that it was a mistake.  All the grieving people who'd felt momentarily clever offering up `* 7` and `n << 3 - n` should have been better sports and deleted their answers.  There are a couple interesting answers to the question as now posed, thanks to zvio and Guido García, but too much noise to make this question worth reopening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n*7 == (n<<3) - n
```

Not sure if that will be better then normal multiplication by 7 though

Comment: i got this thought...but you are using - operator here!!is that correct?I did not tell this since it has a - operator

Comment: Note there will be an overflow in the n<<3 term for suitably large values of n, where this would not be a problem with n*7.

Comment: @Rahul: in your question you say that the operators `*`, `/`, `+` and `-` are allowed, no ?

Comment: It should be (n << 3) - n.  '-' has higher precedence than '<<'.

Comment: @paul its a typo error,changed it

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your compiler isn't terrible, `n*7`.

Comment: To clarify for the downvoters: I posted this answer while the question still said "to to use any of the `+, -, *, /` operators." Also, `-` is in that set.

Answer (score 10):

Meets almost all your requirements :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mult7(int i)
{
    int res;
    __asm__("imull  $7, %1, %0" : "=r" (res) : "r" (i));
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d", mult7(12)); //output: 84
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Based on the nature of the question, this is the best answer I come across by reading this far.

Comment: Something tells me that's not going to work very well on my various ARM, MIPS, PowerPC and Coldfire target CPUs.  (I'm sure you know that, I'm just an embedded guy who is rubbed the wrong way when an Intel architecture is assumed ;-)  )

Answer (score 7):

No forbidden operators (`+`, `-`, `*`, or `/`) used :)

```
/* multiply by 7 without using the forbidden operators */
/* if `n` is larger than `INT_MAX / 7`
** or smaller than `INT_MIN / 7`
** the behaviour is undefined. */
int mult7(int n) {
  int n7 = n;
  n7 *= 7;
  return n7;
}
```

Comment: return n *=7; // solution in single line

Answer (score 5):

The correct answer is a combination of

```
a) n*7
```

because this is exactly the kind of micro-optimization that the compiler is perfectly capable of figuring out on its own.

```
b) the interviewer has a poor understanding of modern optimizing compilers
```

Alternatively, if the interviewer isn't clueless, an answer different than a) above suggests that the interviewee does not understand optimizing compilers and is thus a poor candidate for the job. :-/

Answer (score 5):

The best answer I can come up with is to write "+" operation using while loop and bitwise operators per each bit. Something like this:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
  int a, b;
  do {
    a = x & y; b = x ^ y; x = a << 1; y = b;
  }while(a);
  return b;
}
```

And then sum up n, n << 1, n << 2.

"+" is easy to write with while loop, if you can come up with way to write "-" with while loop (which i am not sure how to do exactly) than you can do (n << 3) - n.

source:http://geeki.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/adding-two-numbers-with-bitwise-and-shift-operators/

Comment: If you don't mind assuming twos complement, `-` is just adding `1+~x`.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely either

```
n*7
```

or

```
(n<<3) - n
```

Comment: how can u say n*7 when i already mentioned to u that we cannot have `+-*/`the first

Comment: That's not what your question says: _"she told me to to use any +,-,*,/ operator"_

Comment: It should be (n << 3) - n. '-' has higher precedence than '<<'.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a valid answer as well : `pow(10, log10(n) + log10(7))`

Comment: +1: nice, (though as presented it doesn't handle negative `n` - easy to fix).

Answer (score 1):

oh you were so close!

= (n << 3 - n)

= n * 8 - n

= n(8 - 1)

= n * 7

Comment: Come on, people.  Every answer here has incorrect operator precedence.  It's not gonna work.  It should be `(n << 3) - n`.  Please be careful.

Comment: Subtraction is not allowed, per edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the interviewer is looking for a shift-and-add kinda answer, I guess you could use:

```
int ans = (num<<2) + (num<<1) + num;
```

I guess this a crude way of testing if the interviewee knows of this particular algo.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
   {
        int i;
        int x;
        int n;
        x = n;
        for (i = 2; i < 8; i++)
        {
             n += x;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT: converted to c (i think) and realized there is no .= in c so had to switch to +=. Still not the same as + technically but a bit questionable.

I know it uses the ++ but that certainly not the same as "+" and .= avoids the stipulation.

Comment: For all its faults, the question is at least clearly tagged as `C`,

Comment: Wow, my bad. Still a usefull answer. If you can't convert my generic for loop into your language of choice you need to look into a new occupation/hobby.

Comment: see if you can convert your "generic loop" into C without using the operators specified in the question. Also it looks like you have at least one bug in your code, which you might want to fix first.